# iTunes failing to sync an iTunes U playlist to my iPhone

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone

I am having problems syncing iTunes U content to playlists on my iPhone. I have a playlist with podcasts, audiobooks and iTunes U content and when I sync only the books and podcasts are in the playlist, the iTunes U content is on the phone just not in the playlist and I can't add it on the phone.

I have ticked the box on the iTunes U tab in iTunes specifying to include the content in Playlist.

Any clues would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a new iPhone 4 and it seems to be a bug.

My workaround is to use iTunes to right click, **Get Info**, **Edit (multiple items)** and change **Options** -> **Media Kind** to *Podcast*. Then my iPhone syncs. Suddenly, when creating a new playlist and I choose **More** -> **Podcasts**, I can add the items with the `+` sign and they finally stay/save.